# How to change the output after running multinom() in R

Tags: r, output, regression, stata

Dear Stackoverflow community,

The default output R produces after running `multinom()` from the nnet package only includes the coefficients of the dependent variables, the residual deviance and the Akaike Information Criterion. Unfortunately, there is no information whatsoever on the number of observations used at fitting the model, the Wald Chi Square and the pseudo-R2, which `Stata` provides after a multinomial logit. How could I get these model statistics after `multinom`? I am particularly interested in the number of observations, the pseudo R2 and the Wald-chi2 and its significance.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible. You didn't even specify to which package does the `multinom` function belongs.

Answer (score 0):

At least to get Wald, you should install and load the 'car' package, 
And then you can use Anova (note this is different from the lowercase 'anova').
There is a worked example here:
http://www.datavis.ca/courses/VCD/R/output/wlf-glogit.html