# How to get the number of observations included in a model created using the function multinom in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial, nnet

I am learning how to use and interpret the output from `multinom()` of the package `nnet`in R. The dataset I use for the exercise contains variables with some missing values. I believe that the observations containing missing values are excluded from the multinomial regression when using this fonction. I would like to know how I can get the number of observations that were included in the model.

A similar question was asked about a year ago  ([How to change the output after running multinom() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012082/how-to-change-the-output-after-running-multinom-in-r)) but this specific aspect of the question was not answered. I am hoping this time someone will have an answer.

My dataset contains 42 variables and 593 observations. To illustrate my question, I ran a model with the outcome of interest (4 groups) and 3 covariates (2 with some missing values).

The output is:

```
model=multinom(GROUP ~ female + BMI + born_Canada, data)
   # weights:  20 (12 variable)
   initial  value 679.284237 
   iter  10 value 637.285180
   final  value 637.129747 
   converged

summary(model)
Call:
multinom(formula = GROUP ~ female + BMI + born_Canada, data = data)

Coefficients:
  (Intercept)     female          BMI born_Canada
2   0.2827215 -0.1446951  0.007395264   0.1870738
3   0.5513568 -0.3101297 -0.007632127   0.1948097
4  -0.3698947 -0.5663595 -0.024331298   0.6115428

Std. Errors:
  (Intercept)    female       BMI born_Canada
2   0.6753277 0.2694006 0.0197283   0.4484126
3   0.7161380 0.2806695 0.0215023   0.4632981
4   1.0415322 0.3829313 0.0312360   0.6920262

Residual Deviance: 1274.259 
AIC: 1298.259
```

From this, what is the command I need to write to get the number of observations analyzed? Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`fitted()` extracts the model's fitted values:

`nrow(fitted(model))`

Comment: Sometimes it's also `length()`, because the result is a vector. This is the case e.g. for `logitmfx()` and presumably other regression from the `mfx` package.

Comment: @MERose Can you expound on using `length()` to get the number of observations of a `logitmfx()` or other models in the `mfx` package? If I fit a model called model: `model <- logitmfx(dv ~ iv1 + iv2, data = df, robust = FALSE, clustervar1 = "iv3", clustervar2 = "iv4")`, the output doesn't provide the N and `length(model)` doesn't provide the correct N either.